# how to add .rc file to a project in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, npapi

I need to add a `.rc` file and corresponding `resource.h` to existing c++ project using eclipse. It seems that there aren’t many materials about this. How to do it? OR **How to make a plugin to be detected by Firefox?** (given the .so file has been generated successfully)

(The project is the npruntime example of NPAPI from Mozilla.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're on linux/unix, which it sounds like, there are no .rc things that need to be done to let the browser detect it, you just need to expose the correct entrypoints and respond to them intelligently.

For example, [FireBreath](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginAuto/X11/np_x11main.cpp) exposes these entrypoints:

```
extern "C" char * NP_GetPluginVersion()
extern "C" const char * NP_GetMIMEDescription()
extern "C" NPError NP_GetValue(void *future, NPPVariable variable, void *value)
extern "C" NPError NP_Initialize(NPNetscapeFuncs* pFuncs, NPPluginFuncs *pluginFuncs)
extern "C" NPError NP_Shutdown()
```

See also http://npapi.com/tutorial

Comment: thx. Morover, I found that in np_entry.cpp, there are clauses like: `pluginFuncs->newp       = NewNPP_NewProc(NPP_New);`, etc in `NP_Initialize`, it cannot compile because no `NewNPP_NewProc(), NewNPP_DestroyProc()....` found. How can I fix this?

Comment: It turned out that these functions are declared in `npupp.h`, which isn't included in _npruntime_ example; it is a must if you wanna build this example in linux. Also, `nprt.rc` and `resource.h` are generated automatically after the example been built

Comment: well, it seems that `nprt.rc` and `resource.h` are not required to produce the final .so file. I didn't add those tow files to my project but I don't know somehow sometime it's been added after/while I built it